# save values in bison in a recursive rule

Tags: parsing, recursion, bison, string-concatenation

I have an issue in storing a string in a recursive rule in bison.
I'm using $$ and a dummy variable for save all the values.
Here I'm going to report a list of what it should happen and
what really happen.

The parser try to match a regular expression, such as "a = b + c"

- input a = b + c
- assignement_line is matched and buf become "a = b"
- buf is stored in $$
- a new assignement_line followed by a TOK_OP(the token for the operation) and TOK_ID(the token for the identifier) are matched (it means that the parser match the "+ c" part)
- dummy_buf value is "a = b"
  here is the problem:

  - buf should become "a = b + c" instead it become "+ c"
  - dummy_buf value is "+ c"

as you can see I've lost all the first part of the string and I dont understand.
I'm reporting a semplified rule section I'm using.

```
lines:
    | lines line
    ;

line: assignement_line
    ;

assignement_line: TOK_IDENTIFIER TOK_EQUAL TOK_IDENTIFIER 
        {
            snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3);
            $$ = buf;
        }
        |assignement_line TOK_OP TOK_IDENTIFIER
        {
                char *dummy_buf;
            dummy_buf = &buf;
            snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s %s %s", dummy_buf, $2, $3);
            $$ = buf;       
        }                   
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "simplified example" reflects your actual code, then you need to fix your use of `snprintf` (and there are probably other issues).

There is really no point in using `dummy_buf` in the following:

```
char *dummy_buf;
dummy_buf = &buf;
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s %s %s", dummy_buf, $2, $3);
```

This does not make a copy of the string in `buf`, so you might as well have just written:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s %s %s", buf, $2, $3);
```

But that code exhibits *undefined behaviour*. Here's a little quote from `man snprintf` on a system using the GNU libc:

> Some programs imprudently rely on code such as the following
>
> `sprintf(buf, "%s some further text", buf);`
>
> to  append  text to buf.  However, the standards explicitly note that the results are undefined if source and destination buffers overlap when calling sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf().  Depending on the version of gcc(1) used, and the compiler  options employed, calls such as the above will not produce the expected results.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer!  I have used the sprintf() in that way because I followed a tutorial. Now I have changed the snprintf part with a chain of strcat() and the code is working well. I thought the problem was with the bison grammar rule (since I'm new to that) but I was wrong!